# How to pass dynamic json structure to cucumber test

Tags: java, regex, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

Here is my feature file,

```
 Given user raises a referral to supervisor
    When user raises a referral by passing "<entityName>","<entityHeaderDetails>",<newEntityDetails>"
    Then user recieves a referral created status
Examples:
    | entityName       | entityHeaderDetails | newEntityDetails|                
    | Approval Process | {"url": "http://localhost:9909/essence/feus/v1/b2e/user","httpMethod": "POST","headers": {"x-tenant-id":"ESSENCE","Content-Type": "application/json"}} | {"activeFlag": "Y","activeFrom": "2022-10-19","activeTill": "2022-10-31","alternatePhone": "9111111113","bankCode": "MODELBANK","emailId": "MCTestUser@mail.com","mobileNumber": "9111111114","readOnlyFlag": "N","userBankDetail": [{"activeFlag": "Y","activeFrom": "2022-10-19","activeTill": "2022-10-31","bankCode": "MODELBANK","bankRoleDetail": [{"activeFlag": "Y","activeFrom": "2022-10-19","activeTill": "2022-10-25","branchCode": "BRANCH_002","defaultRoleFlag": "Y","roleCode": "B2E_SYSTEM_ROLE","roleName": "Bank Employee system Role"}],"branchCode": "BRANCH_002"}],"userCategoryCode": "BANK_EMPLOYEE","userLanguageCode": "en_GB","userLoginId": "MCTestUser","userTypeCode": "NORMAL"} |
```

So trying to get the same in test file and tried this,

```java
 @When("^user raises a referral by passing \"([^\"]*)\", \"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"$")
    public void userRaisesAReferralByPassing(String entityName,String entityHeaderDetails, String newEntityDetails) throws Throwable 
    {
```

Cucumber is able to identify the test method and it calls the same. But mapping of values is failing.

For example the above value of `{"url": "http://localhost:9909/essence/feus/v1/b2e/user","httpMethod": "POST","headers": {"x-tenant-id":"ESSENCE","Content-Type": "application/json"}}`  is mapped as `{"url": "http://localhost:9909/essence/feus/v1/b2e/user`.

Comment: Could you format the question properly, please?